# Jquery limit text in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to limit number of chars in input text field.

Code I'm using:

```
function limitText(field, maxChar){
    if ($(field).val().length > maxChar){
       $(field).val($(field).val().substr(0, maxChar));
    }
}
```

Event is onkeyup.
When I type some text in input field cursor stays on the end of text but focus is backed on start of the text so I can't see cursor.

What can be a problem.

Browser is FF, on IE and chrome it is working correctly

Answer (score 44, accepted):

you can also do it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10" />
```

to achieve this with jQuery, you can do this:

```
function limitText(field, maxChar){
    $(field).attr('maxlength',maxChar);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code is working in FF. Here is slightly modified version of your code:

```
$('input.testinput').on('keyup', function() {
    limitText(this, 10)
});

function limitText(field, maxChar){
    var ref = $(field),
        val = ref.val();
    if ( val.length >= maxChar ){
        ref.val(function() {
            console.log(val.substr(0, maxChar))
            return val.substr(0, maxChar);       
        });
    }
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BPXmK/2/)***

Comment: Best way in JQuery I found to do this ! Cool !