# How do I integrate keyup() to make a character counter via CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, keyup

I am currently building the section of my site where the user edits their profile. In each category, where they fill out their info, there is a textarea that has the number of characters they are allowed to type. I am trying to get the numbers to countdown as they type. Basic key up. How and what, is the best way to integrate this feature in code igniter? Are there helpers that code igniter provides for this? I am new to this all together.

Here is the code I'm trying to apply this to:

```
<div class="edit_section_title">

            My Life <br /><span class="edit_section_sub">Tell us a about yourself <span class="edit_sub_text">(1350 character limit)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_text_area">

        <?php
        if(empty($user['mylife']))
        {
            echo form_textarea('mylife');
        }
        else
        {
            echo form_textarea('mylife', $user['mylife']);
        }


        ?>  

        </div>
        <div class="edit_section_title">
            Occupation <br /><span class="edit_sub_text">(200 character limit) 
        </div>
        <div class="edit_input_area">
            <?php 

            if(empty($user['occupation']))
            {
                echo form_textarea('occupation');
            }
            else
            {
                echo form_textarea('occupation', $user['occupation']);
            }

            ?>
        </div>

thanks in advance
```

Comment: Check this out: [Jquery limit text in input box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410868/jquery-limit-text-in-input-box)

Comment: that works for limiting it. Adding the maxlength="10" that is,however I am trying to get my character limit "1350" to count down backwards as the user types in the text area. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a jQuery solution you may use along these lines. For example, for a `textarea` with `name` attribute set to `myLife` as shown in your question.

```
<textarea name="myLife"></textarea​​​​​​​​​​​>
```

1. Add `maxlength` attribute to your `textarea`. This will instruct the browser to limit the maximum number of characters to the a given size.

   ```
   <textarea name="myLife" maxlength="1350"></textarea​​​​​​​​​​​>
   ```
2. Add an element with `data-limit-for` attribute to hold the number of characters left. The value of the `data-limit-for` is the value of the `name` attribute of the `textarea` element that you want to link it to. In our case, it is `myLife`.

   ```
   <span data-limit-for="myLife">200</span> characters left
   ```
3. Use the following script to update the `span` element with every stroke. The script will apply to any `textarea` with a `maxlength` attribute and with a `span` element with a `data-limit-for` attribute linking to it.

   ```
   $(function() {
       $("textarea[maxlength]").each(function() {
           var $this = $(this);
           var maxlength = $this.attr("maxlength");
           var $span = $("[data-limit-for=" + $this.attr("name") + "]");
           $this.on("keyup blur", function() {
               $span.text(maxlength - $this.val().length);
           });
       });
   });​
   ```

You can repeat steps #1 and #2 for other `textarea` or `input` elements.

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/B9W3f/)

Comment: This is the preferred approach, however it's not doing anything. Here is what I have in the header: <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery_version171min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $("textarea[maxlength]").each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var maxlength = $this.attr("maxlength");
     var $span = $("[data-limit-for=" + $this.attr("name") + "]");
     $this.on("keyup blur", function() {
         $span.text(maxlength - $this.val().length);
     });
 });​
 </script>

Comment: and here is what I have in html, I haven't hooked it up to my specifics just trying to get what you wrote to work: <textarea name="life" maxlength="200"></textarea><br/>
 (<span data-limit-for="life">200</span> characters left)

Comment: @LightningWrist, you didn't put the script between in a `$.ready`. I thought it was clear. Anyways, I updated my answer with a ready wrapper

Comment: I'm afraid there is a hidden problem because that is not working either. Any idea what I should be looking out for?

Comment: @LightningWrist, no idea. Maybe not including jQuery?

Comment: @LightningWrist, you are copying some illegal characters along the source. Go to http://jsbin.com and paste the code. Any red dot will be an invisible character that you copied from jsfiddle

Comment: @LightningWrist, did that make it?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the keydown event, it will result in a much more responsive gui.

http://jsfiddle.net/9BfR2/4/

html:

```
<textarea data-max-length="1350" data-target="#theinput"></textarea>
<input size="4" id="theinput">​
```

javascript:

```
var timer;
$("textarea[data-max-length]").on("keydown cut paste input",function(){
    var self = $(this), 
        maxlength = $(this).data("maxLength"), 
        target = $( $(this).data("target") )[0];
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        if (self.val().length > maxlength) {
            self.val(self.val().substr(0, maxlength));
        }
        target.value = maxlength - self.val().length;
    },0);
}).triggerHandler("keydown");​
```

Comment: I like this logic. Where would I put the input portion in my code?

Comment: It can go anywhere you want it to be, though i would suggest right after the textarea.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to do this with all of the elements I have already and not add anymore. Is that possible to do without inputs?

Comment: Yes, just replace the input with a span(or whatever), as long as it matches the selector that you pass into `data-target`

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the basic idea:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(".edit_text_area textarea").keyup(function(){
     if($(this).val().length > 1350){
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 1350));
    }
  });
</script>
```

Or use that:

```
$(function(){
        $(".edit_text_area textarea").prop('maxlength',1350);
      });
```

Comment: Where is #mylife coming from?

Comment: #mylife refering to textarea generated by >> echo form_textarea('mylife'); << This is just a example as i dont know what HTML code is generated here. But see my update

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#a').keypress(function(e) { // you can give your textarea id here #yourid
    var count = 1350; // <----------max character limit
    var a = parseInt(count - $(this).val().split('').length);//<-- counting the characters
    if (a == 0) { // <----- if limit exceeds stop the keypress event.
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('character limit exceeded.'); // <---and alert the msg.
    }
    $('span').html(a);// <--- shows the characters left
});
```

find this in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2hqt/1/

This is just a basic idea.

Try and see if this helps you.

Comment: Type `XXXXXXXXXXXX` and copy paste it for several in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @siamak.A.M OP want to calculate the characters on the keypress.

Comment: Backspace also fails, probably context menu too(though i suspect mine will also fail in that aspect).