# Laravel and Jquery Var Length

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I need to create a validation for my input to limit it 10 char,
I dunno why my code doesnt work

```
{{ Form::label('send-txt', 'Category Code', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
{{ Form::text('code', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Category Code')) }}


  $(document).ready( function() {        
        var maxLen = 10;

        $('#send-txt').keypress(function(event){
            var Length = $("#send-txt").val().length;
            var AmountLeft = maxLen - Length;
            $('#txt-length-left').html(AmountLeft);
            if(Length >= maxLen){
                if (event.which != 8) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

});
```

I used laravel 4.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery limit text in input box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410868/jquery-limit-text-in-input-box)

Answer (score 1):

You can validate it with HTML5 attributes too.

```
{{ Form::text('code', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Category Code', 'maxlength' => 10 )) }}
```

And as commented above, maybe you are not referencing the correct html element in your JQuery validation code. So change **$('#send-txt')** to **$('#code')** (Don't forget to add the **ID** attribute to your input)